# Is an irreducible, asymmetric adjacency matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I am wondering whether the following statement is true or not. My computer has so far not been able to provide me with any counterexamples, nor have I been able to find much in the way of arguments to support it. I might just be missing something obvious, but I'm hoping that someone is able to help me. The statement is:

*Let $D$ be a simple, directed graph with adjacency matrix $A\in\{0,1\}^{n \times n}$. If $D$ is strongly connected, then $A$ is diagonalizable.*

Kind regards,
Pepijn

Edit: somehow managed to forget the essential requirement in the body of the question.

Comment: How about the graph with two vertices and one edge?

Comment: I forgot the put the "strongly connected" requirement in the body of the question; while an order 2 digraph with one arc would indeed not have a diagonalizable adjacency matrix, its adjacency matrix is also not irreducible, which was what I was looking for in the first place. My mistake, sorry!

Comment: For the case of random matrices (a generalization of random graphs), see https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1438. (Simple spectrum implies diagonalizability.)

Answer (score -1):

Take $$ A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} %A={{0,1,0},{1,1,1},{1,0,1}}$$
The directed graph of this matrix is strongly connected,which implies $A$ is irreducible.
But this matrix is not diagonalizable, since $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$, and $\operatorname{rank} A=2$.

Comment: If you want to type a matrix, you can use MathJax, which has LaTeX syntax. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference